# Adding Media button to only pages

Tags: php, theme-development, pages, admin

I have created a media button as such:

```
    // Create a media button for pages
function aisis_page_button_link(){
    global $post_ID, $temp_ID, $iframe_post_id;
    $iframe_post_id = (int) (0 == $post_ID ? $temp_ID : $post_ID);
    $url = admin_url("/admin-ajax.php?post_id=$iframe_post_id&codes=aisis-page-codes&action=aisis_page_codes&TB_iframe=true");
    echo "<a href='".$url."' class='move thickbox' title='Create amazing pages with these codes!'>
    <img src='".get_template_directory_uri() . "/lib/images/pages.png" . "' width='16' height='16'></a>";
}

if(!empty($_GET['codes']) && $_GET['codes'] == 'aisis-page-codes'){
    add_action( 'parse_request', 'parse_wp_request' );
    echo parse_aisis_page_request($wp);
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_asisi_page_codes', 'parse_aisis_page_request' );
}

function parse_aisis_page_request($wp){
    aisis_require_page_code_display_page();
    exit;
}

function aisis_require_page_code_display_page(){
    require_once(CORETHEME_SHORTCODES . 'PageCodes.phtml');
}

add_action('media_buttons', 'aisis_page_button_link', 999);
```

Which then creates the desired effect of:

[image]

**Note:** The above code is for the second "page" like icon.

What I want to do is only have the above code run on pages, and only pages. that is edit and add new page. I know I would edit the `aisis_page_button_link()` function, and I can figure out how to make it appear for adding a new page, how ever how do you make it appear for editing a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check the post type](http://queryposts.com/function/get_post_type/):

```
function aisis_page_button_link(){
    global $post_ID, $temp_ID, $iframe_post_id;

    if ( 'page' !== get_post_type( $post_ID ) )
        return;

    // continue
```

Comment: interesting. thnx